# Split hyphenated nvarchar value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, temporary-tables, string-splitting

I have a table with 6 columns one of which is a NVARCHAR (65) datatype.

All of the entries in this table have the format XXXXX-nnnnnn.

I want to be able to use the '-' as a delimiter and construct a query that pulls out the value after the '-' into a temporary table so I can run another query against a column containing just the nnnnnnn values.

I believe PATINDEX needs to be in there somewhere but it all seems hard and difficult.

Comment: A split function seems overkill for this. Just use `SUBSTRING(yourcol,1+ CHARINDEX('-',yourcol),65)`

Answer (score 3):

In this spirit of showing a man how to catch a fish, I'll provide a few possibilities that should point you in the right direction.  First, we need to have a  test table, with some test data, so we can try some things:

We'll do this in `tempdb`, so we don't affect anything important:

```
USE tempdb;
```

Here, we'll create the table:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.Split', N'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE dbo.Split;
CREATE TABLE dbo.Split
(
    SomeCol varchar(65) NOT NULL
);
```

And insert 10 rows of data:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Split (SomeCol)
SELECT 'SomeData-0000000' + CONVERT(varchar(10), r.num)
FROM (VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8), (9))r(num);
```

There are several methods you might choose to "split" the `SomeCol` column data.  If the portion you want to split off is always a consistent number of digits, you could use the `RIGHT` function.  If the portion you need to split away from the right-hand-side is variable length, you could use `SUBSTRING` and `CHARINDEX`.

[RIGHT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/right-transact-sql) returns the right part of a character string with the specified number of characters.

[SUBSTRING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql) returns part of a character, binary, text, or image expression.  [CHARINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql) searches an expression for another expression and returns its starting position if found. Used together, SUBSTRING and CHARINDEX can slice-and-dice strings in numerous ways.

```
SELECT *
    , [RIGHT] = RIGHT(SomeCol, 6)
    , [SUBSTRING/CHARINDEX] = SUBSTRING(SomeCol, CHARINDEX('-', SomeCol) + 1, LEN(SomeCol))
FROM dbo.Split
```

The results:

```
╔═══════════════════╦════════╦═════════════════════╗
║ SomeCol           ║ RIGHT  ║ SUBSTRING/CHARINDEX ║
╠═══════════════════╬════════╬═════════════════════╣
║ SomeData-00000000 ║ 000000 ║ 00000000            ║
║ SomeData-00000001 ║ 000001 ║ 00000001            ║
║ SomeData-00000002 ║ 000002 ║ 00000002            ║
║ SomeData-00000003 ║ 000003 ║ 00000003            ║
║ SomeData-00000004 ║ 000004 ║ 00000004            ║
║ SomeData-00000005 ║ 000005 ║ 00000005            ║
║ SomeData-00000006 ║ 000006 ║ 00000006            ║
║ SomeData-00000007 ║ 000007 ║ 00000007            ║
║ SomeData-00000008 ║ 000008 ║ 00000008            ║
║ SomeData-00000009 ║ 000009 ║ 00000009            ║
╚═══════════════════╩════════╩═════════════════════╝
```

If you are using SQL Server 2016 or newer, you could use the [`STRING_SPLIT` functionality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-split-transact-sql) to automatically split the contents of the column into multiple columns:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Split
CROSS APPLY string_split(SomeCol, '-') ss;
```